# Run and evaluate imported text file in place as Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, oop, inheritance

I have some Python code that is generated dynamically and stored in a text file. It basically consists of various variables like lists and strings that store data. This information is fed to a class to instantiate different objects. How can I feed the data from the text files into the class?

Here is my class:

```
class SomethingA(Else):
    def construct(self):
        // feed_data_a_here
        self.call_method()

class SomethingB(Else):
    def construct(self):
        // feed_data_b_here
        self.call_method()
```

Here is some sample content from the `text_a` file. As you can see, this is some valid Python code that I need to feed directly into the object. The call the `call_method()` depends on this data for the output.

```
self.height = 12
self.id = 463934
self.name = 'object_a'
```

Is there any way to load this data into the class without manually copying and pasting all of its from the text file one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write a parser for your files which would delete 'self.' at the beginning and add the variable to the dictionary:

```
import re

# You could use more apprpriate regex depending on expected var names
regex = 'self\.(?P<var_name>\D+\d*) = (?P<var_value>.*)'
attributes= dict()
with open(path) as file:
    for line in file:
        search = re.search(regex, line)
        var_name = search.group(var_name)
        var_value = search.group(var_value).strip() # remove accidentalwhite spaces
        attributes[var_name] = var_value

foo = classA(**attributes)
```

[example of the regex in work](https://regex101.com/r/88cuxR/1)

#### Edit

If you use the code I've proposed, all items in the dictionary will be of the string type. Probably you can try:

- `eval()`, as proposed by @Welgriv but with small modification:

```
eval(f'attributes[{var_name}] = {var_value}')
```

- If your data consists of standard python data and properly formated you can try using `json`:

```
import json

x = '12'
y = '[1, 2, 3]'
z = '{"A": 50.0, "B": 60.0}'

attributes = {}
for i, v in enumerate([x, y, z]):
    attributes[f'var{i+1}'] = json.loads(v)

print(attributes)

# Prints
# {'var1': 12, 'var2': [1, 2, 3], 'var3': {'A': 50.0, 'B': 60.0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably look for the [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function. It evaluate and try to execute a python expression as text. For example:

```
eval('print("All your base are belong to us")')
```

Will print the sentence. In your case you should open the text file and then evaluate it.

#### Remarks

- `eval()` function present some security issues because the user can potentially execute any code.
- I'm not sure what is the overall context of what you try to implement but you might prefer to store your data (name, id, height...) in another way than python code such as key-values or something because it will make your application extremely dependent of the environment. As an example, if there is a python update and some code are deprecated your application will not work anymore.

Comment: It seems your example doesn't work. `exec('a = 3')`  does.

Comment: @PoorStandard indeed thanks, I edited and take a working example